# 100% CPU consumption while establishing WebSockets connection

Tags: javascript, performance, websocket, cpu-usage, readystate

I try to write a function which connects to the WebSocket server. The problem occurs when this server is down. This function should wait for it, even for long time, but it shouldn't consume 100% of CPU. Here is my code:

```
var state = {
    connected: false
};

var settings = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1988
};

function connect(settings) {
    try {
        var socket;
        var host = 'ws://' + settings.host + ':' + settings.port;
        var socket = new WebSocket(host);

        socket.onopen = function() {
            state.connected = true;
        }
        // socket.onmessage
        socket.onclose = function() {
            state.connected = false;
            connect(settings);
        }

    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

So I need to somehow pass an interval to the WebSocket constructor, it looks like it simply tries to open a connection in a loop, killing performance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket is immediately closing when you attempt to connect, causing you to try to connect again. Add an interval between tries:

```
socket.onclose = function() {
    state.connected = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        connect(settings);
    }, 1000);
}
```